# NetBeans 7.1: No current context on hover over in Java debugger

Tags: java, netbeans-7.1

I'm working on a Mac 10.6.8 with NB 7.1 and Java 1.6.0_29.

Here's an example scenario:

When I hit a break point in my code, there is a boolean member variable called `traceEnabled`.  If I hover over the code with my mouse arrow, I intermittently get a tool tip message that says `traceEnabled > No current context <`.  If I move the mouse away, then hover over it again, the true/false value may or may not show up.  It eventually does after a variable number of tries.  There is no change in the debugger between subsequent tries: I haven't stepped or ran or opened any watch windows or anything.

Note that this scenario also happens with highlighted member functions and local variables.  It also happens within the Watch window and the way I get the value to show up there (even though the variable is in scope and has not gone out of scope), is to step a few times.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I installed 7.1.1 along side 7.1 (using a copied netbeans.conf file) and the issue is not there in 7.1.1.  Seems like it was a bug that was fixed in the patch.  I'll answer my question tomorrow (can't answer it yet according to house rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this was a bug in 7.1.  Updating to 7.1.1 made the problem go away.